# Cómo hacer scroll down automaticamente a una pagina con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

me gustaría saber si es posible hacer scroll down de forma automatica a una pagina y cómo podria hacerlo?
Veran, tengo un pequeño codigo thml el cual consta de un input text y un boton. por medio del input se ingresa una url y al darle click al boton se abre esta url en una nueva pestaña, esto ultimo lo hago por medio de jquery, utilizando "window.open()".

Aqui el codigo que llevo hasta ahora:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#boton").click(function() {
                          var url = $("#inputURL").val();
                          window.open("https://"+url);
                        });
                            });
```

```css
h3 {
 color: #FF5665;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #F5F5F8;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #FF5665;
 padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>URL Tabs</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h3 id="saludar">Ingrese su URL</h3>
    
    <input name="urlUser" type="text" id="inputURL" /><br>

    <input type="button" name="send" id="boton" value="Start" class="btn btn-success" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

Mi duda es: Cómo podria hacer scroll down a la pagina que se ha abierto en la nueva pestaña? Es posible? El scroll seria hasta llegar al final de la pagina.

Comment: En principio no puedes ejecutar javascript en una página que no es tuya.

Comment: ni siquiera si lo hago por medio de una extensión de google chrome o firefox? Estaba pensando crear una extensión para chrome y ver si por medio de ella podia hacerlo

Comment: Desconozco las características especificas de las APIs de cada navegador, pero seguramente es posible hacerlo a través de extensiones.

Comment: @RolandF a la pagina que quieres darle scrolldown es tuya?

Comment: no es mia la pagina, pero he encontrado la manera de hacerlo por medio de una extension de google chrome que he creado.